# Spotify API authentication doesn't redirect with access token

Tags: authentication, oauth-2.0, spotify

I'm using the Spotipy library, which uses the Spotify API. When I attempt to get my access token using the 'Authorization Code Flow', I get sent to a spotify web page that asks for me authenticate the access of the app to my user's data. When I click the Okay button, that's supposed to redirect me to my redirect_uri with the access token, it simply does nothing. I get no error message or anything. When I click the Cancel button, I do get redirected to my redirect_uri page, but I don't receive the access token. Is this a bug with the API? Am I doing anything wrong?

I added the redirect_uri to the whitelist of redirect pages in my app's page by the way.

Comment: Are there any console errors on the Spotify Accounts page?

Comment: I get the following error during the initial loading of the page:
Refused to load the script 'data:application/javascript;base64,KGZ1bmN0aW..(long base64)' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' https://d2d1dxiu3v1f2i.cloudfront.net https://www.google-analytics.com".
When I click the Okay button I get the following error:
POST https://accounts.spotify.com/en/authorize/accept 500 (Internal Server Error)

Comment: Ok - I believe that's an internal Spotify error. Is it still happening?

Comment: It's still happening, yes.

Comment: Alright, would you mind adding some more of your code, or, ideally, a link?

Comment: [This is the link](https://accounts.spotify.com/en/authorize?scope=user-read-currently-playing&redirect_uri=http:%2F%2Flocalhost%2F&response_type=code&client_id=2eb6f769c3bd4297a445fc13a4311b33).


token = util.prompt_for_user_token(USER, scope, client_id='2eb6f769c3bd4297a445fc13a4311b33',client_secret='<my_secret>', redirect_uri='http://localhost/'). This is the spotipy line that prompts the accounts.spotify page. 

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Well, that's a fun bug!  I'll check it out when I have a chance

Comment: Appreciate you help! :D

Comment: I'm getting this EXACT same error as well. Any updates?

Comment: Checked up on this. Make sure your `redirect_uri` is EXACTLY the same as the one you have saved in the developer dashboard, right down to the http and the trailing slash. Looks like the error for invalid redirect URIs isn't being handled properly.

Comment: That actually did it. Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

The answer for this for future readers: Make sure your `redirect_uri` is EXACTLY the same as the one you have saved in the [developer dashboard](https://beta.developer.spotify.com/dashboard), right down to the http and the trailing slash.